# Wordpress doesn't update file on live site?

Tags: wordpress, ftp

Long story short: I f**** up a live website and now it won't revert my changes despite rewriting them manually on the files laying on the ftp.

In the wordpress editor I can access the files laying on the site. I changed the color on an element to #fff but forgot the ';' symbol. Now the typo persists and I can do nothing to change it. I've tried changing it both in the wordpress editor and on the file on the ftp. Changing another file in the same directory is no problem. No it is not a cache problem.

If anybody know a way to troubleshoot this I would appreciate it a lot. This website is as I said live and my customers.

Comment: Q: You're aware that *MOST* of the HTML content in a typical WP site is stored in the *DATABASE*, aren't you?  STRONG SUGGESTION: [updraftplus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) is your friend.  Get it.  Use it.

Comment: @paulsm4 No I was not. I barely know anything about databases. This is CSS content and I changed it once (that time it worked). Does that matter? Will check it out.

Comment: @paulsm4 Now it miraculously updated without me doing a thing. It took about 2 hours for it to update. What's up with that? Sorry for being a noob but I really don't see the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the site is using a caching plugin then you may need to clear the cache before the changes are visible. The fact that you say that it took two hours to update points to this as the issue. Make the change then clear the cache.

Here are some examples: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/recommended-wordpress-plugins/clearing-cache-in-wordpress